Firestore API states index does not exist when it does
I'm using the Java Firestore library to access my Firestore database. I am making this Query:
Query chatQuery = firestore.collection("chats")
  .whereEqualTo("userId", userId)
  .orderBy("seq", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

// userId is already defined.

When I run it, it gives this error:

io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/...

However, my firestore index for the collection chats exists:

How do I fix this?

Did you click the link provided in the error message to create the index that it says is missing?

I was able to figure out the solution: I was running 2 different queries in my code, and so I needed 2 different indexes.


The error was not wrong, I was.
